# Applying XGBoost on train & test data

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, xgboost

I have two data, train & test in a csv file, which has over more than 385 features, same are loaded as `df_train` & `df_test` respectively.

I have identified the target feature (target column) to be as 'y', column y is not available in the test dataset provided, i.e in `df_test`.

Before applying the XGB, I have applied PCA as under,

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA 
pca = PCA(n_components = 0.95)

df_train = pca.fit_transform(df_train)
df_test = pca.fit_transform(df_test)
```

After that I have tried to apply XGBoost as follows,

```
import xgboost as xgb
params = {'ntrees':520,'eta':0.0045,"booster":"gblinear", "objective":"reg:linear"}

x_train = df_train.drop('y',axis = 0)
y_train = df_train['y']

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(x_train,y_train)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(df_test)


xg_reg = xgb.train(params = params,dtrain=df_train,num_boost_round=5)
preds = xg_reg.predict(df_test)

#to find the accuracy
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,preds))
print("RMSE: %f" % (rmse))
```

**Output**

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'drop'

It would be appreciated to guide me where I'm going wrong.

**Requirement** --> splitting `df_train` to train & test, and to build a model & predict same on `df_test` & calculating its accuracy.

Comment: This is because after performing pca on `df_train` a numpy array is returned and not a dataframe. Since numpy arrays have no method `drop`, the error is returned.

Comment: You are trying to drop the column using `df_train.drop('y',axis = 0)` AFTER you have converted `df_train` to an numpy array with `df_train = pca.fit_transform(df_train)`. Hence the error

Comment: So to overcome that I need to split x_train & y_train from ```df_train``` before I perform PCA & apply PCA on x_train & df_test?